# how do i loop and create a menu with multiple sub menu levels in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I am using Vue and I have the array of objects and I need to use it to create a menu using that.

The array list looks like the following:

```
[{
    "name": "Menu 1",
    "url": "/link/menu-1",
    "sub-menus": []
},
{
    "name": "Menu 2",
    "url": "/link/menu-2",
    "sub-menus": [
        {
            "name": "Menu 2-1",
            "url": "/link/menu-2-1",
            "sub-menus": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Menu 2-2",
            "url": "/link/menu-2-2",
            "sub-menus": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Menu 3",
    "url": "/link/menu-3",
    "sub-menus": [
        {
            "name": "Menu 3-1",
            "url": "/link/menu-2-1",
            "sub-menus": [
                {
                    "name": "Menu 3-1-1",
                    "url": "/link/menu-3-1-1",
                    "sub-menus": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Menu 3-2",
            "url": "/link/menu-2-2",
            "sub-menus": []
        }
    ]
}]
```

Since there are multiple sub-menu levels, I have no idea how to generate the menu dynamically.

The level of sub-menu is not fixed. It can be no sub-menu or more than 2 or 3 levels.

I want the output to be something like the following.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="/link/menu-1">Menu 1</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/link/menu-2">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/link/menu-2-1">Menu 2-1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/link/menu-2-2">Menu 2-2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Since i am new to Vue, i have no idea how this can be achieved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with two components.

One that will build a menu for itself and it's sub ones :

```
var Menu = ({
  name:"Menu",

  template: `
    <li>
        <a :href="url">{{name}}</a>

        <ul v-if="subMenus.length > 0">
          <Menu 
            v-for="menu in subMenus" 
            :name="menu.name" 
            :url="menu.url" 
            :subMenus="menu['sub-menus']">
          </Menu>
        </ul>
    </li>`,

  props: {
    name:     {type:String, required:true},
    url:      {type:String, required:true},
    subMenus: {type:Array, required:true}
  }
})
```

And another one to insantiate everything, that will iterate over your menu list (that you will pass as a prop) :

```
var FullMenu = ({ 
  components: {Menu},

  name:"FullMenu", 

  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Menu 
          v-for="menu in menus" 
          :name="menu.name" 
          :url="menu.url" 
          :subMenus="menu['sub-menus']">
        </Menu>
      </ul>
    </div>
    `,

  props: {
    menus: {type:Array, required:true}
  }
})
```

Just use it like this:

```
<div>
  <full-menu :menus="yourMenuListAsDataOrProps"></full-menu>
</div>`
```

Here is a running example on Observable : https://observablehq.com/d/802261a535698d88#FullMenu

Comment: Thank you. I will try your method and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue like below way:

use this in template section =>

```
<span v-html="hasChild(chart)"></span>
```

and hasChild method =>

```
hasChild(chart){
  var html = ''
  if(chart.childs.length>0){
    html = html+'<ul>'
    chart.childs.map(child=>{
      html = html+'<li>'
      html = html+'<a>'+child.title+'</a>'
      if(child.childs.length>0){
        html = html+this.hasChild(child)
      }
      html = html+'</li>'
    })
    html = html+'</ul>'
    return html
  }
}
```

and work fine for me.